# grub2 installation failed with Ubuntu / Windows 8 dual boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I have an HP Pavilion g6 2320tx with Windows 8 preinstalled in UEFI mode. I tried to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8, but it failed every time giving me the error that grub2 was not installed.

I followed  these steps.

1. I disabled Secure Boot and disabled Legacy mode. (I have tried enabling legacy mode and installing Ubuntu, but that also failed.). Here is a screenshot of the boot option of my laptop before I tried to install Ubuntu.

   [image]
2. After this I restarted and booted Ubuntu from a USB flash drive. Before getting into Ubuntu it gives the below screen for a split second.

   [image]

This comes every time i did this procedure(i ignored this msg btw :P)

3. After getting into Ubuntu I chose to install Ubuntu and I created:

   - 4096MB swap partition
   - boot 500MB boot partition
   - the rest of the disk space for Ubuntu
   - This is my partition space.

   [image]

   [image]
4. These are the options I was getting in the bootloader installation and I selected `/dev/sda`

   [image]

   [image]
5. Everything went smoothly from now until installing the grub2 package appears during the installation I managed to click this line which appeared in the logs under installation.

   [image]

   [image]

   [image]
6. In the end GRUB installation failed.

   [image]
7. A few things which I have tried but which failed.

   - Tried Boot-Repair from live USB
   - Tried both disabled/enabled Legacy mode
   - Checked that my USB is flashed in UEFI mode
   - Connected to internet
   - Tried with all other options that were available from the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i figured out what the problem was.
Its the 23rd time i installed(Yes i was counting :P)

So it was all about fast boot , it was ON,
i thought that fast boot option is available on the BIOS settings and in hp i was not able to see any such thing so i assumed that there is no such thing in HP :P

But in many laptops its not in the BIOS
you have to turn it off from the windows

So for people like me (especially using HP laptops) 
follow these steps

1. Make sure secure boot is off

   - Start your laptop and keep pressing F10
   - BIOS will open. now go to System Confirguration and then select boot   options
   - NOW select Secure boot and choose disable
   - Press escape and save and exit . REMEMBER TO SAVE AND EXIT OTHERWISE IT WILL NOT SAVE YOUR SETTINGS(you can find save and exit in the exit tab)
2. Turning Off fast boot

   - now open your windows , go to control panel(Those who dont know how to - press start+Q type control panel and open it[windows 8 + method])
   - now go to power options or search for power options if you are not able to see by pressing ctrl+F and typing power options
   - Now open power options and in the right side you'll see 'Choose what the power button do'. Click this .
   - Now you will see 'Change settings that are currently unavailable '. Click this and scroll down
   - You will see an option of fast boot . make sure that it's not checked
   - Now save changes and exit

So yeah! That was pretty much it.

Now try to install ubuntu the usual way and if you face any problem ,mention it , i'll try to help you out

Answer (score 0):

When you have the product key, you could try a complete fresh installation of both, Windows and than Ubuntu. 
Where do you install grub? `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdaX`?
You can also try to install grub from a live disk. I don't know the exact command, but it should be something like `grub-install /dev/sda`. You need `chroot` before

Comment: boot-repair also tries to reinstall the grub I guess

Comment: And I have also tried the boot repair but nothing had happened then