# Grub2 package failed installed on dual boot with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I have a problem when I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as secondary OS. I used windows 10 before and I want to make dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I already create 30GB free space on the disk and I already make USB boot too. I followed the steps to install Ubuntu and make one partition as swap and one as ext partition. I used "Something else" method in this case. But, when I installed it works well in the first copying and installing but when Grub2 package installed I have some error said like this :

> The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/.
>   Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot".

I used HP laptop with 4GB RAM and I used windows 10 to make free space of partition. I also use rufus to make bootable from USB device.

Anyone please help me to solve this problem. Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

As I found in this post  [GRUB2 Installation failed Dual boot ubuntu with windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760633/grub2-installation-failed-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-8?rq=1).

Follow these steps
*Make sure secure boot is off
Start your laptop and keep pressing F10.
*BIOS will open. Now go to System Confirguration and then select boot options.
NOW select Secure boot and choose disable.
*Press escape and save and exit . REMEMBER TO SAVE AND EXIT OTHERWISE IT WILL NOT SAVE YOUR SETTINGS(you can find save and exit in the exit tab)
*Turning Off fast boot
now open your windows , go to control panel(Those who dont know how to - press start+Q type control panel and open it[windows 8 + method]).
*Now go to power options or search for power options if you are not able to see by pressing ctrl+F and typing power options
*Now open power options and in the right side you'll see 'Choose what the power button do'. Click this .
Now you will see 'Change settings that are currently unavailable '. Click this and scroll down
*You will see an option of fast boot . make sure that it's not checked.

Now save changes and exit

Now install Ubuntu the usual way...